# How to decrypt c when phi(n) and e are not relatively prime

Tags: rsa

I have read multiple websites to see what would happen with RSA when $\phi(n)$ and $e$ are not relatively prime, but no one has discussed it.

Can someone explain how to decrypt $c$ if $\phi(n)$ and $e$ aren't relatively prime?

Comment: This is the exact dupe : [In RSA encryption, why does the public exponent (usually, 'e') have to be coprime with $\varphi(n)$?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/80303/18298)

Comment: Actually, the https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/81949/how-to-compute-m-value-from-rsa-if-phin-is-not-relative-prime-with-the-e/81966#81966 answer addresses the specific question Yolo asked

Comment: This answer was moved [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/83593/555) since it fits that [other question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/43660/555) well.

Comment: @poncho The answer was moved, you could copy above comment there if you want, as the mods seemingly cannot.

Comment: Regarding _Can someone explain how to decrypt $c$ if $n$ is prime, and $\phi(n)$ and $e$ aren't relatively prime?_: have you checked [poncho's answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/81966/555) which has a large intersection with your case?

Comment: When $n$ is prime than it is not RSA. It is [Pohlig-Hellman Cipher](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/77798/18298). I've roll-back your edit. If you really consider $n$ is prime, then please read about Pohlig-Hellman Cipher. In RSA, we need at least two distinct primes...